# How to center a horizontal navigation bar

Tags: html, css, centering, nav

I am having trouble centering my navigation bar.

This is the example nav bar I am working with

```
<style>
/* Begin Navigation Bar Styling */
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li {
  float: left; }
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #069;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #c00;
  background-color: #fff; }
/* End navigation bar styling. */
</style>
```

but as seen, the navigation bar is not centered.

I have tried using auto margins but it doesn't work. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Please post your code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `text-align:center;` to `#nav`

Remove `float:left;` and add `display: inline-block;` to `#nav li`

Change to this:

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F2gUg/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-block;
```

This should center the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

try this new css:

```
   #nav {
      margin: 0 0 3em 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
      position: relative;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
   #nav li {
      display: inline-block;}
   #wrap {
      width: 750px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #fff; 
      text-align: center;
      width:100%;}
```